# When doing bitwise operations in C#, do I ever have to consider the CPU besides x64 or x86?

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, micro-optimization

I'm considering doing some Bitwise operations in C# and want to make sure I take full advantage of the CPU and bus.  I'd also like to structure my in-memory data so it doesn't incur unnecessary load (aligning data to memory pages).

Can I, as a .NET developer, implement hardware/CPU specific optimizations with regard to in-memory data structure and alignment?

Comment: The best bet is to first make your program work, then to profile it to see where the performance problems are, and only _then_ to optimize it.

Comment: what type of operations, specifically?

Comment: @MarcGravell Bit shifting, Bitwise comparisons, etc.  I'm working with many arrays of up to 10,000 bits and am thinking of ways I can shoot myself in the foot.

Comment: Pay attention to John's comment.  Also, as .NET developer why worry about hardware, its will always change.  The goodness about C#/.Net is you don't care; Jitter will optimise for you.  If you are so concerned about these issues then use C or better yet assembler (tongue firmly implanted in check).

Comment: @JohnSaunders I +1'd your comment too (as a general practice).  All QA Unit tests passed and I have spare time to explore this.  I don't know if I have a performance problem, since I have nothing to compare it to.  This question will allow me to create an "optimized" baseline for comparison.

Comment: @makerofthings7: use a performance profiling tool to at least determine _where_ in your code you're spending your time. It will also give you a baseline against which to judge your optimizations. You don't want to solve the wrong problem.

Comment: @makerofthings7 - So you are asking about wet noodles to throw at the wall?  Doing a bit operation on 10,000 bits is an expensive operation, that isn't a small chunk of change, depending on the size of the array.  The only thing you should be aware of is the fact the smallest chunk of change will be slightly larger on x64 then x86 hardware.  But there is nothing you can do about this fact except be aware of this fact and only load ( into memory ) small groups of chunks at a time.  More information would be require, code to demo what your doing, otherwise where's the question?

Answer (score 1):

For things like bit-shifting (comments), it won't matter as long as you are working at standard data boundaries - the CPU will shift in a way that respects the endianness of the CPU. However, if your data is "naturally" a byte-array, and you treat it as a long-array as an optimisation via "unsafe", then it *will* matter: left-shifting a long is very different to left-shifting 8 bytes independently. The "lie about the data type" can be a useful optimisation, though: for example, web-sockets masking is done as a 32-bit xor applies to the data, which is a byte-sequence. With some trickery, that can be done as a reduced number of 64-bit xors, plus at most 7 individual xors.

Answer (score 1):

You can control the in-memory representation of data with the [FieldOffsetAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.fieldoffsetattribute.aspx).  This is part of the class/struct's definition so it can't change at runtime, though you could optimize one for x86 and one for x64 and decide at runtime which to use.

The title of your question asks something different, though.  As long as you are doing your bitwise operations via built-in operations the runtime will take care of mapping your code to the sematically-equivalent instructions.  What I'm trying to say is that:

```
byte f(byte a, byte b){return a ^ b;} // or whatever
```

has to behave the same on every platform that it runs on.  Marc Gravell's comments do apply if you are doing this "unsafe"-ly.  Which is maybe what you intend to do - it's a little unclear to me.

Comment: I am new to low level programming and had a feeling the title didn't reflect the body of the question.  My goal is to see what can C# do with regard to low-level operations?  Your example of FieldOffsetAttribute is interesting and relevant to what I'm looking for.  What revisions would you suggest?

Comment: I don't have any first-hand experience, and it depends on what you want to do.  If you're planning on treating 8 bytes like as a 64-bit long, you do have to understand the C# semantics of that (as Marc says) but I would guess that's how you're going to get your main performance improvements.  But depending on your situation it might make more sense to just write this critical code in unmanaged C++ and make different x64 and x86 binaries.  Then you have full access to everything you could want.